# The Application has stopped unexpectedly?

Tags: c#, android

I am using Android application with C# ,
My application involved
1-creating database and table
2 insertion-updation-deletion
3-Android 2.1
Application working perfectly in emulator , but after installing successfully in Tablet
 i am getting this error during open the application while my tablet also have same android ver2.1.
Here is my some code i want know if something wrong in it ?

```
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Android.OS;
String Path_ = new databse.db().Database("netdobrasil.sqlite");
public string Database(string DbName)
{
var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
var pathToDatabase =  Path.Combine(documents, "netdobrasil.sqlite").ToString();
SqliteConnection.CreateFile(pathToDatabase);
return pathToDatabase;
}
```

Comment: If your application stopped, there should be an exception in the log. Finding that exception should be your first port of call - it's *vital* that you can diagnose problems yourself.

Comment: If your Android application crashes (which is what happening), that's where the problem is, not in your C# code.

Comment: how to get exception please it might be helpful for me ? how to use try{}catch{} condition ?

Comment: Sorry, we cannot help you if you are trying to debug a Android/C# client server system and do not know how to use `try...catch`. Start learning the languages first.

Comment: ok thanks, i was looking about this but could not get.

Comment: please someone either take me out of this problem or i have to change xamarin to Netbeans. why emulator works perfectly and not my device ?